# dhcp query to get IP by MAC

Tags: bash, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

I am using `CentOS 6.5` and `Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.1.1-P1`

I found this file /var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases but not simple to parse it in bash

is there any way to get the online clients or commend to get IP by MAC?

Comment: The programmatic way to access this is via OMAPI, or possibly dbus if you've installed the dbus bridge. `omshell` is a CLI client.

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if you included a sample of the file for those of us who don't use this system.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work. Note that you need to have an OMAPI key configured in your `dhcpd.conf`.

```shell
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 mac-address" >&2
    exit 1
fi

(
    echo key omapi_key YOUR_KEY_HERE
    echo connect
    echo new lease
    echo set hardware-address = $1
    echo open
) | omshell | grep '^ip-address ='
```

Note that it outputs in omshell's weird hex-IP format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arp, I'm on Ubuntu:

```
user@host:~$ arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
hostnameforhost          ether   00:0c:29:90:7b:ad   C                     eth0
10.10.20.4               ether   00:0c:29:90:7b:cd   C                     eth0
```

Then you can nslookup with the "Address" field or it will have the IP depending on your DNS.

Edited for formatting

Comment: That will only work if they're on the same Ethernet network, which isn't always the case with, e.g., DHCP relay, and will also only work if this machine has communicated recently with the other machine (otherwise, it won't be in the arp cache)